# How does (int) casting work on char arrays and char *?

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-literals

Well, I believe I've searched enough and I couldn't find any explanation on this.

When you cast a `char` to an `int`, that is okay and obvious.

```
char foo = 'a';
int bar = (int)foo;
printf("%i",bar); //Outputs 97 as expected.
```

But when you try to `cast` a `char *` or a `char` array to an `int`, the compiler just gives you a warning:

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

For a `char *` you get a constant `int` value - I believe that has something to do with pointers or memory - then for a `char` array you always get some variable `int` value.

```
char* foo = "baz";
int bar = (int)foo;
printf("%i",bar);

char qux[]="something";
int bar2 = (int)qux;
printf("%i",bar2);
```

This might sound like an unnecessary question but I would like to know the reason.

Comment: So sure this has to be a duplicate.

Comment: `int bar = (int)foo;` casting is redundant.

Comment: "try to cast a string literal " --> Code does not do that here.  `(int)foo` casts  a `char *`, a pointer, to `int`.

Comment: When an array-valued expression appears in a context such as you describe, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the array's first element.  Thus it's a pointer you're converting either way.

Comment: @SouravGhosh `(int)foo;` quiets warnings that would otherwise arise when assigning a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: C permits converting pointers to integer types.  This has nothing to do with the data, if any, to which the pointer points -- it's about the value of the pointer itself.

Comment: @chux I was talking about the first case...

Comment: "you try to cast a string literal or a char array to an int, the compiler just gives you a warning"  --> What is the exact text of the warring?  A warning is not expected when a cast is present.

Comment: @chux Here it is 
main.c:62:15: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
     int bar = (int)foo;
               ^
main.c:66:16: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
     int bar2 = (int)qux;

Comment: @PorFavorDama Exaclty, because the compiler knows that there is a size mismatch. Try `intptr_t` instead of `int` and the warning will go away. You will then be able to print the address of the pointer. Note that you can directly do this by using the `"%p"`. You can of course use this `intptr_t` variable to get back your pointer.

Comment: "the compiler just gives you a warning".... Take warnings seriously... most likely you are doing something bad - and in this case you are.

Comment: looks like we have a serial downvoter

Comment: [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551525/how-does-casting-work-on-char-arrays-and-string-literals?noredirect=1#comment84100460_48551525) [Tough Crowd](http://na.frea.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/tough-crowd-no-respect-dbff09_zpsdc78f8f6.jpg?itok=MQSNcPmn) today.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi [re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551525/how-does-casting-work-on-char-arrays-and-string-literals/48551995#comment84100075_48551525) `"%p"` is for `void *`,  `"%" PRIdPTR` is for `intptr_t`.

Comment: @chux I see how you can think that I said *use `"%p"` with `intptr_t`* but I didn't mean to. I meant that one could directly print the address using the pointer and the `"%p"` `printf()` specifier.

Comment: @PorFavorDama I'm editing the post to reflect that you are really asking about an `(int)` cast of a _pointer_ and not a _string literal_.  `(int)"xyz"` would be an `(int)`cast of a _string literal_.  Re-edit/roll-back if needed.

Comment: @gsamaras so look it up and flag it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attempting to convert a pointer to some *integer* type can potentially cause *undefined behavior*  (UB).

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. **If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined.***  ...  C11dr §6.3.2.3 6

The `(int)foo` can generate a warning like "warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size" because of that UB potential.  [@4386427](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551525/how-does-casting-work-on-char-arrays-and-string-literals/48551995#comment84100338_48551525)

```
char* foo = "baz";
int bar = (int)foo;  // potential UB.
```

---

To avoid that UB, when converting *object pointers* to integers,  (not *function pointers*), use the optional types  `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`.

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> `uintptr_t`
>   7.20.1.4 1

Example

```
#include <inttypes.h>

some_object* foo = ...;
uintptr_t bar = (uintptr_t)(void*)foo;  // no UB

printf("0x%" PRIXPTR "\n", bar);
```

---

> for a char array you always get some variable int value.

That is because the conversion of the array, first converts to a pointer to the first element and then to the integer.  `int bar2 = (int)qux;` is trying to get the value of where the array exists, not its element values.

Comment: PorFavorDama, `int bar = (int)foo;` did not generate a warning as the `int` and the `char *` are the same size on my compilation.  When I used `int bar = (int16_t)foo;`, I received the same warning as you.  [@Iharob Al Asimi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551585/2410359) answer about the _potential UB_, not _certain UB_ was very useful.

Comment: The answer isn't sastified. What's about `char qux[]` ? Since isn't the pointer. if i try to print it with `%d` im going to get integer value like `-299211190`, what is that?

Comment: @TomSawyer `qux` as in `char qux[]="something";` is an [array 10 of char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+qux%5B10%5D).  With `printf("%d", qux);` converts the `qux` to the the address of `qux[0]` ( a `char` pointer) so it is like `printf("%d", &qux[0]);`.  Printing a pointer with `"%d"` is undefined behavior.  Use  `printf("%p", qux);` to print a `char *` and see its address value.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to convert an object pointer `p` to an integral type is `(uintptr_t)(void*)p`, or `(intptr_t)(void*)p` if for some reason you want a signed type.  An `int` or `long` are frequently 32 bits wide on 64-bit targets, but `uintptr_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`, is always the right size to hold a pointer. Technically, the standard only says that the conversion to and from `void*` is safe, hence the intermediate cast.

This gets you a representation of the address of your string.  If what you really want is to read a number in ASCII format, you want something such as `atoi()` or `sscanf()`.

Comment: Although POSIX does implicitly require function pointers to be convertible to `void*`. Other safe things to do with a *function* pointer include: `memcpy()` to an array of `unsigned char[sizeof((*void)(void))]` or `typedef void (*funcptr)(void)`.

Comment: However, this question was specifically about `char*`. I'll add a qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

Conversions between pointers and integers are accepted by the c standard, but they might easily lead your program to [*undefined behavior*](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6).

If you were presented with a situation where converting between pointer and integer is useful, and there are situations<sup>1</sup>. Then you should use the [appropriate types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdint.h),

- `intptr_t`
- `uintptr_t`

You should probably read these

- [What is the motivation for casting a pointer to a integer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290574/what-is-the-motivation-for-casting-a-pointer-into-a-integer)
- [INT36-C Converting a poitner integer or integer to pointer](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT36-C.+Converting+a+pointer+to+integer+or+integer+to+pointer).

Also, the actual type of a character constant *is* `int`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>For example in a *jni* plugin to pass a *handle* to java and from java to your program.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

When you cast `char *` to `int`, you get memory address of first element in char array.

```
char* foo = "baz";
int bar = (int)foo;
printf("0x%X", (unsigned)bar); //It will print memory of first char element.
```

But, this code has major issues and may not print exact result. Memory address can have MSB bit set to 1 and you will get negative value in int or in some cases `int` is not enough wide to store entire memory address.

Comment: Note that a memory address may exceed the width of an `int`.

Comment: @tilz0R Simply because you should not use `int` for that, there are types more suited for it. I will lookup the part of the standard that explains why this is UB.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi It is not UB.  "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type." 6.3.2.3 6  True, other types may be better, but it is not UB.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I simply casted to `int`. If I have loss of data, who cares. In the next step, I'm using printf completelly ok. What UB can I trigger with this cast? What can happen in system? Memory leak? I don't believe.

Comment: @tilz0R [Here it is](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6), the behavior is *strictly speaking* undefined. Specifically "*if the result cannot be represented ... the behavior is undefined*", whether you convert back or not, the standard says so.

Comment: @tilz0R Nothing that has to do with *loss of data*, the BEHAVIOR IS UNDEFINED. But there are integer types that are guaranteed to allow this conversion, and back from it. [Read my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551585/1983495).

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi what behavior? Where is this noted. Sorry, but I don't believe you this time. You have no facts :)

Comment: @tilz0R Click the links in my comment please. It's not a matter of *believing*.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi  Fair enough, it (pointer to integer) may be UB if the result is not representable.  Else it is IDB.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I said it clear. int may not be enough for entire pointer. But there is no problem in casting pointer to int. UB would be if you would use this int to cast back to pointer and then dereference it.
`char* a = "abc"; int b; int* c; b = (int)a; c = (int *)b; printf("%d", *c);` Printf statement is UB here

Comment: tilz0R, @IharobAlAsimi  is correct in the case of the pointer not representable as the target integer.  Code is UB _at that point_.  Rest of code does not matter.  Using _optional_ integer types `(u)intptr_t` avoids this problem for _object pointers_.

Comment: @tilz0R You are contradicting the standard. [Please read the following link, exactly where it opens, i.e. Paragraph 6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6).

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi you did not post any standard. You example code shows clearly what I said earlier. If you do not cast back to pointer and dereference this pointer, everything is ok. I will change my mind if you show me STANDARD, not some "good coding practice". Period. End of discussion.
Edit: I read your exact part. It says it is undefined due to the fact that you cannot write entire address to int. Clearly, but until you dereference it again, everything is ok!

Comment: @tilz0R Click the link, that's all you need to read. I will not post it here. And NOOOO you don't have to dereference anything for it to be UB. Read the *** link please, and then say whatever you want: this is the link ---> https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6